is there a simpler way to make rounded corner Surface
I need to have a rounded corner Surface, with a dashed line.
I found a way to make it work, but I think there should be a simpler way, or a direct API to achieve it, does anyone know?
@Composable
fun testRoundCornerSurface() {

    Surface(
        color = Color.Cyan,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        modifier = getBorderModifierModifier().then(Modifier.height(56.dp))
            .padding(2.dp)
    ){
        Text(" test Surface")
    }
}

fun getBorderModifierModifier(): Modifier {
    val dashWidth = 10.dp
    val dashGap = 5.dp
    val dashedBorderModifier = Modifier.drawWithContent {

        val path = Path().apply {
            val cornerRadius = 8.dp.toPx()
            moveTo(cornerRadius, 0f)
            lineTo(size.width - cornerRadius, 0f)

            quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0f, size.width, cornerRadius)
            lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerRadius)

            quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width - cornerRadius, size.height)
            lineTo(cornerRadius, size.height)

            quadraticBezierTo(0f, size.height, 0f, size.height - cornerRadius)
            lineTo(0f, cornerRadius)

            quadraticBezierTo(0f, 0f, cornerRadius, 0f)
            close()
        }

        val stroke =
            Stroke(
                width = 2.dp.toPx(),
                pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                    floatArrayOf(
                        dashWidth.toPx(),
                        dashGap.toPx()
                    ), 0f
                )
            )


        drawPath(
            path = path,
            color = Color.Blue,
            style = stroke,
        )
        drawContent()
    }
    return dashedBorderModifier
}




To create a Surface with rounded corners and a dashed border in Jetpack Compose, you can achieve this by creating a custom Modifier using the drawWithContent modifier. Unfortunately, there isn't a direct API in Compose to apply PathEffect to a border, so you'll need to manually draw the dashed path. Here's a concise solution:
Step-by-Step Solution

Create a Custom Modifier: Define a custom Modifier.dashedBorder
extension that handles the drawing of the dashed border with rounded
corners.
Apply the Modifier: Use this custom modifier in your Surface to
achieve the desired effect.

@Composable
fun RoundCornerSurface() {
    Surface(
        color = Color.Black,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(56.dp)
            .padding(2.dp)
            .dashedBorder(2.dp, Color.White, 8.dp, 10.dp, 5.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "test Surface",
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    }
}

fun Modifier.dashedBorder(
    borderWidth: Dp,
    color: Color,
    cornerRadius: Dp,
    dashWidth: Dp,
    dashGap: Dp
): Modifier = this.drawWithContent {
    val path = Path().apply {
        val cornerRadiusPx = cornerRadius.toPx()
        moveTo(cornerRadiusPx, 0f)
        lineTo(size.width - cornerRadiusPx, 0f)

        quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0f, size.width, cornerRadiusPx)
        lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerRadiusPx)

        quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width - cornerRadiusPx, size.height)
        lineTo(cornerRadiusPx, size.height)

        quadraticBezierTo(0f, size.height, 0f, size.height - cornerRadiusPx)
        lineTo(0f, cornerRadiusPx)

        quadraticBezierTo(0f, 0f, cornerRadiusPx, 0f)
        close()
    }

    val stroke = Stroke(
        width = borderWidth.toPx(),
        pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
            floatArrayOf(dashWidth.toPx(), dashGap.toPx()),
            0f
        )
    )

    drawPath(path = path, color = color, style = stroke)
    drawContent()
}


Preview:


this is cool, nice
